# How to fix multiple messages from Push Subscription in GCP Pub/sub

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Cloud Pub/Sub Push subscription that pushes multiple instances of the same messages to a processing end-point i GAE. I can track the message ID and it’s the same message that gets PUSH multiple times.

I have set the ack-timeout to 600 seconds but still it pushes multiple instances of some of the messages. Outside of the message doesn’t get “acked”, what can trigger this behavior? Anyone had the same problem?

The issue seems to be bigger the more instances I run, but even when using basic_scaling and with max_instances: 1 problem still remains.

I can see a bunch of 503 errors in GAE but if I understand it correct, that is not an issue since these messages automatically gets "re-tried" but Pub/Sub.

Comment: Can you share the code (or the simplified version) ? Something is going wrong.

Comment: Code in GAE doesn't really matter. As it turns out this is a well known issue with Pub/Sub. Pub/Sub is "At least Once Delivery", and duplicates are to be expected. To rsolve this, read here for some inspiration, https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions

Answer (score 4):

I am posting this as an answer, because i dont have enough reputation to put as comment. :)

As you have already figured out, once Pub/Sub sends a message to a subscriber, the subscriber should acknowledge the message. Any message that has not been acknowledged, Cloud Pub/Sub will repeatedly attempt to deliver (Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery)). This means that occasional [duplicates](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq#duplicates) are to be expected. However, a high rate of duplicates may indicate that the client is not acknowledging messages within the configured ack_deadline_seconds, and Cloud Pub/Sub is retrying the message delivery. 
You could use Stackdriver, to [monitor](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring) if the Pub/Sub System is successful and your messages are being acknowledged (Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting#messages) & [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#receiving_push_messages)), or if there are too many duplicates (Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq#duplicates) & [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting#dupes)).

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out this is a well known issue with Pub/Sub. Pub/Sub is "At least Once Delivery", and duplicates are to be expected. To resolve this, read here for some inspiration, https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions